# stdout is empty

Tags: shell, stdout

When a run the command:

```
cellprofiler --get-batch-commands "/users/pmrotem/CellProfiler/example_project/output/Batch_data5_8.h5"
```

in the shell, I get an output:

```
CellProfiler -c -r -b -p /users/pmrotem/CellProfiler/example_project/output/Batch_data5_8.h5 -g Metadata_Plate=20140602-LOPAC pilot_Assay Plate 0_5
CellProfiler -c -r -b -p /users/pmrotem/CellProfiler/example_project/output/Batch_data5_8.h5 -g Metadata_Plate=20140602-LOPAC pilot_Assay Plate 0_6
CellProfiler -c -r -b -p /users/pmrotem/CellProfiler/example_project/output/Batch_data5_8.h5 -g Metadata_Plate=20140602-LOPAC pilot_Assay Plate 0_7
CellProfiler -c -r -b -p /users/pmrotem/CellProfiler/example_project/output/Batch_data5_8.h5 -g Metadata_Plate=20140602-LOPAC pilot_Assay Plate 0_8
```

However when I try to output it to a file (I add `>test.txt`) I get an empty file.
I also tried to invoke the command through python and also get empty stdout.
stderr is also empty in both cases.

What is the problem? any ideas?

Comment: Is it empty, or is the output buffered? Do you check the content of test.txt while the program is running or after it has finished?

Comment: Try it like `CellProfiler ... > test.txt 2>&1`, maybe it's outputting to stderr.  ([See this for the ordering](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#order_of_redirection_ie_file_2_1_vs_2_1_file))

Comment: @sr_ I had the same idea but OP said: "stderr is also empty in both cases"

Comment: i check the content at the end.

Comment: @lgeorget, rotmus0: eek, didn't look close enough.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Maybe the Wiki is useful: [headless operation](https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler/wiki/Adapting-CellProfiler-to-a-LIMS-environment#headless-operation); also there's the source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs behave differently when they are connected to a terminal to when they aren't (see the [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) function). To make the application think it is connected to a terminal, you could try `script -c`:

```
script -c cellprofiler --get-batch-commands \
 "/users/pmrotem/CellProfiler/example_project/output/Batch_data5_8.h5" \
  >test.txt
```

Comment: thenk u @Graeme it worked :)